# What alternative ways exist for sending updates through REST?

Tags: rest

I was trying to get my head around the possible alternative ways to structure a GET or POST call in REST.

(This is not homework, more like just attempting to get a better understanding of the options.)

Here are the alternatives I have gathered so far:

1. GET-based calls

   - Following alternatives exist for structuring the submitted parameters:

     - [name]=[value] pairs joined by equal signs and separated by ampersands, sent in:

       - The URL after the URI followed by a question mark.
     - (MATRIX parameters) [name]=[value] pairs joined by equal signs and separated by semicolons, sent in:

       - The URL after the URI before the question mark.
2. POST and PUT-based calls

   - Following alternatives exist for structuring the submitted parameters:

     - JSON, sent in:

       - The content part of the request
     - XML, sent in:

       - The content part of the request
     - [name]=[value] pairs, sent in:

       - The content part of the request
       - The request header

Are there any other ways to structure the parameters?

Comment: Why would you want to send an "update" using GET?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, thanks for asking, "GET" is one of the ways that (according to our integrations department) is used for sending data to some external systems. Some process sends a web app data encoded in the URL. I am not sure of the reason, maybe it is some legacy app that they are calling with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any [hypermedia content type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).  Doesn't mean every client and server will understand every type (which is why we have [content negotation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation)).

Most common are

- application/json
- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/html
- text/xml
- application/xml

Comment: Thanks @John Wu, can any of the hypermedia content types be sent in the header like with the POST and PUT calls?